# Pass variable from one method to another in python/django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I want to pass variable from details method to downloader method and perform operations.I tried several methods but not working

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import pytube
from .forms import VideoDownloadForm
# Create your views here.


def details(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VideoDownloadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.cleaned_data['Url']  
            yt = pytube.YouTube(f) # <-----Pass this 'yt' from here
            thumb = yt.thumbnail_url
            title = yt.title
            return render(request, 'ytdownloader/details.html', {'title': title, 'thumbnail': thumb})
    else:
        form = VideoDownloadForm()
    return render(request, 'ytdownloader/front.html', {'form': form})


def downloader(request): #<----to this method
    videos = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, type='video', subtype='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    videos.download('C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads')
    return render(request, 'ytdownloader/details.html')
```

**details.html**

```
{% extends 'ytdownloader/base.html'%}
{% block content%}
<h1> {{title}}</h1>
<a  href="{{thumbnail}}"><img src="{{thumbnail}}" alt=""></a>
<a href="{% url 'download'%}"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Download</button></a>
{%endblock%}
```

Comment: pytube is no longer maintained, consider using pytube3 instead

Answer (score 0):

function-based views act just like *Python* functions in django, so if you need a variable (`yt` in this case), you should pass it to the function; You can also **call** the `downloader` view, with it's arguments, from your `details` view:

```
def details(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VideoDownloadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            f = form.cleaned_data['Url']  
            yt = pytube.YouTube(f)
            downloader(request, yt)
    else:
        form = VideoDownloadForm()
    return render(request, 'ytdownloader/front.html', {'form': form})


def downloader(request, yt):
    videos = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, type='video', subtype='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    videos.download('C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads')
    thumb = yt.thumbnail_url
    title = yt.title
    return render(request, 'ytdownloader/details.html', {'title': title, 'thumbnail': thumb})
```

Comment: Its working directly but what i want to do is when user paste the link and click start button i want it to display the description like title,thumbnail in another page(details.html)And again when they click Download button on that details.html page it should start downloading.